# Questions regarding transactions on psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, transactions, psycopg2

If I have a transaction that saves data in the database, but this transaction is part of another transaction that needs the id(fk) of that data to create a new data, but an error occurs at that moment, all transactions are rolled back or just the last transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will both rollback unless you set up [savepoints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-transactions.html). A transaction "within transaction" is actually the same transaction. A plain `ROLLBACK` will revert everything, even if there are savepoints set up. A `ROLLBACK TO savepoint` will only undo operations that occured from that point onwards, keeping everything that took effect beforehand, still within the same transaction.

Here's a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/iAoZrttR) - observe the state of the table compared to transaction id.

[Psycopg2](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/faq.html) lets you `cur.execute('SAVEPOINT s1')`, then `cur.execute('ROLLBACK TO s1')`.